# Something's wrong with my Logistic Regression?

Tags: matlab, normalization, logistic-regression

I'm trying to verify if my implementation of Logistic Regression in Matlab is good. I'm doing so by comparing the results I get via my implementation with the results given by the built-in function `mnrfit`.

The dataset `D`,`Y` that I have is such that each row of `D` is an observation in R^2 and the labels in `Y` are either 0 or 1. Thus, `D` is a matrix of size `(n,2)`, and `Y` is a vector of size `(n,1)`

Here's how I do my implementation:
I first normalize my data and augment it to include the offset :

```
d = 2; %dimension of data
M = mean(D) ;
centered = D-repmat(M,n,1) ;
devs = sqrt(sum(centered.^2)) ;
normalized = centered./repmat(devs,n,1) ;
X = [normalized,ones(n,1)];
```

I will be doing my calculations on `X`.

Second, I define the gradient and hessian of the likelihood of Y|X:

```
function grad = gradient(w)
    grad = zeros(1,d+1) ;
    for i=1:n
        grad = grad + (Y(i)-sigma(w'*X(i,:)'))*X(i,:) ;
    end
end

function hess = hessian(w)
    hess = zeros(d+1,d+1) ;
    for i=1:n   
       hess = hess - sigma(w'*X(i,:)')*sigma(-w'*X(i,:)')*X(i,:)'*X(i,:) ;
    end
end
```

with `sigma` being a Matlab function encoding the sigmoid function z-->1/(1+exp(-z)).

Third, I run the Newton algorithm on `gradient` to find the roots of the gradient of the likelihood. I implemented it myself. It behaves as expected as the norm of the difference between the iterates goes to 0. I wrote it based on [this script](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28227-newton-s-method/content/newton.m). 
I verified that the gradient at the wOPT returned by my Newton implementation is null:

```
gradient(wOP)

ans =

   1.0e-15 *

    0.0139   -0.0021    0.2290
```

and that the hessian has strictly negative eigenvalues

```
eig(hessian(wOPT)) 

ans =

   -7.5459
   -0.0027
   -0.0194
```

Here's the wOPT I get with my implementation:

```
wOPT =

 -110.8873
   28.9114
    1.3706
```

the offset being the last element. In order to plot the decision line, I should convert the slope `wOPT(1:2)` using `M` and `devs`. So I set :

```
my_offset = wOPT(end);
my_slope = wOPT(1:d)'.*devs + M ;
```

and I get:

```
my_slope =

   1.0e+03 *

   -7.2109    0.8166
my_offset =

    1.3706
```

Now, when I run `B=mnrfit(D,Y+1)`, I get

```
B =

   -1.3496
    1.7052
   -1.0238
```

The offset is stored in `B(1)`. 
I get very different values. I would like to know what I am doing wrong. I have some doubt about the normalization and 'un-normalization' process. But I'm not sure, may be I'm doing something else wrong.

**Additional Info**

When I tape :

```
B=mnrfit(normalized,Y+1)
```

I get

```
-1.3706
110.8873
-28.9114
```

which is a rearranged version of the opposite of my `wOPT`. It contains exactly the same elements. 
It seems likely that my scaling back of the learnt parameters is wrong. Otherwise, it would have given the same as  `B=mnrfit(D,Y+1)`

Comment: I notice that `mnrfit(normalized,Y+1)` produces the same as my `wOPT` multiplied by -1. Do I renormalize back  `wOPT` as it should be ?

Comment: I think the statistic toolbox ships with the code. If it does, you can compare your implementation vs. their implementation. If this is for an assignment, you shouldn't copy any code.